# In mongoose, User.findOne( {username : req.params.userName} ); not finding some particular documents

Tags: database, mongodb, mongoose, passport.js, url-routing

Inside the database, I manually verified there exists a user with username **R0H1** but when I use the below code it just sends back "No such user". 
The same problem occours with username **Harshitsin75**, whereas it correctly finds all other alphanumeric usernames for example **akhil**, **test123** etc. 
 And this problem occours everytime I try to open the profile for the users **R0H1** and **Harshitsin75**.

```
    app.get("/profile/:userName", function(req, res) {
        if (req.isAuthenticated()) {

            User.findOne({username: req.params.userName}, function(err, foundUser) {
                if (err) console.log(err);
                else {
                    if (foundUser) res.render('User-profile', {user: foundUser});
                    else res.send("No such user");
                }
            });
        } else {
            res.redirect('/login');
        }
    });
```

Comment: can you provide one example of working username and it is the case all the time or random issue?

Comment: it may be related to uppercase/lowercase.

p.s: for authentication you can use a middleware

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```js
Users.find({ username: { $regex: req.query.username }, })
```